# upgrade GIT Command Line

Tags: git, upgrade

I recently started working with Git. When I entered 'git --version' in my terminal, it displayed version 2.15.0. Subsequently, I installed Homebrew and used it to install and upgrade Git. After running 'git --version' again, it displayed version 2.15.0. However, when I attempted 'brew upgrade git,' I received the following warning: 'Warning: git 2.43.0 already installed.' What could be the issue, please?

```
@macbook-pro-2 ~ % git --version
git version 2.15.0
@macbook-pro-2 ~ % brew upgrade git
Warning: git 2.43.0 already installed
@macbook-pro-2 ~ %
```

Comment: You are most likely using a system installation of Git rather than the verison you installed with Homebrew. This could be for multiple reasons, such as installing Xcode on your Mac. You have to update your PATH environment variable to point to the appropriate installation location

Comment: ... or at least _prepend_ in `$PATH` the directory where the homebrew git is present so that it is _before_ the system one.

Comment: Depending on your CPU architecture, the Homebrew version will be in either `/usr/local/bin/git` (Intel) or `/opt/homebrew/bin` (ARM) whereas it seems that you are using `/usr/bin/git`. Troubleshooting your `PATH` is a very common beginner question; please search before asking.